# No internet connection in Virtual Machine on selecting NAT in VMWare workstation

Tags: internet-connection, vmware-workstation, nat

I'm facing this strange problem from yesterday where if I select **NAT** as the network adapter in VMWare, I'm not getting any internet connection in the VM. I have a requirement where I have to have the network adapter as NAT.

Internet is working properly in my host machine but not working in my VM. It shows that the **internet cable is unplugged**. I'm getting a 'X' mark on the internet icon.

Even if I'm connected in Wi-fi or LAN, I'm getting the same issue.

My host machine is Windows 7 Professional and VM is Windows 7 Professional N.

Any idea what could be the problem. I have referred to other links similar to my problem but they didn't seem to provide the solution to mine. Most of them asked to connect using Bridged adapter.

Any suggestions will be very useful.

Comment: Did you shared Host Internet Connection to the NAT VMnet? You can do this from Network and Sharing Center. Follow steps in this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2j3nyl4muQ

Comment: If you land here looking to solve this issue but on a Linux host, see https://superuser.com/a/1722671/157933

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved the problem. Though the solution seems to be pretty lame.

I observed that VMware DHCP service had stopped running and was not restarting at all, no matter what I try.

So I had to uninstall and re-install VMware workstation to make it run.

After reinstallation, I started getting internet with NAT adapter.

But I'm still not sure why the service was not starting.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me!  And I have tried many from various online forums.

Comment: maybe is late, but you should be tryed start>run>cmd and type NET START "VMware DHCP Service" and press enter.

Comment: Hello @FranciscoTapia. Sorry for the late response. I had tried this as well but it kept failing. Tried with cmd prompt in admin mode too but with the same issue. That's why had to resort to this method.

Comment: This worked for me, too.  I had converted (imported) my VM into my new Fusion app.  The VM started up but couldn't NAT.  I uninstalled Fusion, reinstalled, and now my VM has Internet access.

Comment: This might have worked because it implicitly did what the other answer suggests (resetting defaults). https://superuser.com/a/1113669/268750

Comment: I don't think the reinstall was necessary.  I agree the user interface is not intuitive, but I think you could have achieved this without a reinstall.

Comment: Basically my windows OS got an update and VMware didn't start this service for me as well. `VMware DHCP Service` you will have to run `services.msc` as admin to start it again.

Answer (score 27):

> You don't need to necessarily **reinstall** VMware. You might lose custom config and preferences, if you do so.

Here is a simple fix

- Edit > Virtual Network Editor

[image]

- Grant Admin Privileges

[image]

- You shall see all network adapter to configure, tweak those to your needs
- If you don't know what those are, simply click **Restore Defaults**

[image]

Comment: Related: https://danblee.com/vmware-workstation-vms-shows-network-cable-unplugged/

Answer (score 10):

In my case, it was VMWare NAT service that was not running. I started it by going to services.msc and the internet started working on the guest VM. In the Virtual Machine Settings, choose NAT as Network connection.

Comment: This worked for me! My VMWare is set to NAT connection so that's why. So I think the solution is the following:
Go to services.msc and start whichever service corresponds to your type of connection, NAT or Bridged (DHCP), etc.

Answer (score 10):

Came across this issue on Windows 10 - VMware Workstation 15. None of the answers here helped and from the get go all of my VMware related services were running.

The only thing that fixed the issue for me was to go to `Start > type services` and opened the `Services Manager`. Here I found `VMware NAT Service` and right clicked selecting `Restart`:

[image]

Simply restarting the system may have helped but I was looking for a quick fix that didn't interrupt my running Virtual Machine's.

Answer (score 5):

I too had faced the issue, took a long time for me to figure out what was wrong. Finally all I did was to start the DHCP Service from the task manager which was stopped and it worked fine.

[image: task mangaer VMware services -DHCP]

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in a multi Nic card server, you must to select which Nic will be in use.

In VMware Workstation:

1. Go to Edit, Virtual Configuration Network
2. Select the VM Nic auto-bridging
3. In VMNet Information, select bridge, and
4. In the option "bridge to" select the correct NIC card used by the VMware Workstation.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me; not sure why "automatic" no longer worked.

Answer (score 2):

try starting the network service on your VM machine. you can use this command for linux:
sudo nmcli networking on

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Answer (score 2):

I tried every solution except VMWare reinstallation. However simple solution from this [article](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/No-networks-on-Ubuntu-guest-on-new-PC/td-p/2214645) at vmware support worked fine. **Start your VM, then Suspend and Resume** it. **Power off** didn't worked out for my case

My setup:

- Win11 - Host OS
- Ubuntu 20.04 - Guest OS
- VM Ware Workstation Pro 16.2.3 build-19376536

Comment: You saved my life bro

Comment: I am very much surprised, but this solved the problem for me, too.  (Restoring defaults of VMware networks: no. Power-off, then power-on: no. Removing virtual network adapter, then re-adding: no. Windows services like VMware DHCP Service were already running, so that wasn't the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, after upgrading to V 17.5. None of the previous answers worked.

- I tried restarting the VMware NAT and DHCP Services.
- I tried deleting the NAT adapter and creating a new one in the guest
- I tried restarting the host and the guest
- I tried reinstalling VMware Tools.

What finally worked was deleting the NAT Subnet in the Virtual Network Editor and adding it back in.

When it added it back in, I even set the subnet IP back to what it was before. So, all settings were identical before and after, but it now works. I don't know why.

Comment: This helped! Thanks! Might add that I needed to re-configure the VM Settings so it used the new NAT based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problems appeared with NAT after a VM pro v15 update.  VM tools upgrade in each VM did not help.  Here's what I did in chronological order :

- "Repaired" VMware (via "control panel" | "add/remove programs") and rebooted the host machine.  This did NOT fix the problem.
- Removed *all* network adapters from VM (Edit | Virtual Network Editors...)
- Added one new NAT... then restored the subnet to what it was previously (with all the network issues it was burned into memory months ago).
- Subsequently started each VM and of course the network was still NOT working each time.
- From the VM (host) menu for each VM I reconfigured the network adapter to "custom" and selected the virtual network I created above.
- The network adapter now works in each VM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed Network Adapter and CD drive and added it again. It worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Mac and would like to reset you can use this link:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2009642

you can continue to run

```
> sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop 
> sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start
```

Answer (score 0):

I powered off the virtual machine. Turned it back on. It worked. Simple as that. Lots of guides even on the VMware community forum didn't work for me.

```
Windows 10
VM Machine: Ubuntu
VM State: I mostly keep VM's suspended, never power off.
Software: VMWare
```

And there was no settings issue either. Just a restart and everything worked as it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it worked for me but internet is working slow now -

**--> Goto windows10(i.e., your Host machine)  start > Run > services.msc**
and over here as @Sabe Barker mentioned restarting the **VMware Nat Service.**

& then coming back to VMware
**--> VM > settings > Network Adapter > NAT > OK**

That's it !!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Linux hosts, these commands restart VMWare network services and reconnect guests:

```
sudo vmware-networks --stop
sudo vmware-networks --start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to fix the problem "No internet connection in Virtual Machine on selecting NAT in VMWare workstation"

It turned out to be a permissions error.

Right clicking C:\ProgramData\VMware on the host computer, going to properties, and making sure the user I was running under, as well as administrators had full control, then changing owner to the user of the host I was running vmware on did it.

I also had to do the same to vmnetdhcp.conf in the above folder.

I found this out by looking in Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System, and looking at VMnetDHCP events.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to an IPV6 network with my host machine was the cause for me. It seems maybe VMWare routing only works with IPV4 host networks.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you should use this command in terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start vmware-networks
```

and make sure the network enabled by checking out network option below in VMWare application. Checkout the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot NIC]

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem and none of the other answers helped.  When I shutdown my VM I noticed that there was an option to "Upgrade This Virtual Machine".  I selected that option, making a clone version to the latest version, and upon restart of the new clone it appeared to be working properly with the NAT setting.

I would suggest trying this option first if your network started acting up after an upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Well, i had the same problem.
My host is Windows 7, VM is Ubuntu and I'm using Workstation.

So i just returned the defaults configuration in the Virtual Network Editor and then everything was ok.

Comment: I tried that as well. But the problem still continued. So had to use the standard "solve everything" solution of uninstalling and re installing the work station. And that worked out for me.

Comment: What is Virtual Network Editor?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It's just a menu option. Go to Edit->Virtual Network Editor on VMware Workstation: https://i.imgur.com/vbV65jA.png

Answer (score -1):

It happens when you shut down your host machine without saving machine state of VM.
You can just restart your virtual machine. It will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm going to give an upvote for the part where you said it happens when you shut down your host machine without saving the machine state of the VM. I just realized that was the cause of the problem, so I know how to troubleshoot it in the future

The solution suggested of restarting the virtual machine does not help, though