# VMWare VMs cannot connect to the internet after enabling Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, networking, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-player

Recently, I had to install Docker on my Windows 10 Machine:

```
Edition         Windows 10 Pro
Version         21H1
Installed on    ‎08-‎08-‎2021
OS build        19043.1237
Experience      Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0
```

For that, I had to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39989990) to get Docker up and running. After Docker was working properly I tried opening one of the VMWare VMs and I saw an error related to side-channel mitigations being enabled. I followed the [solution here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/j2fyfl/how_to_disable_side_channel_mitigations_with/g87z5y5?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to fix it. After I opened the VM, it was not able to connect to the internet. I have already tried restarting the VMWare NAT and DHCP services as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/q/733166/476582).

Comment: Try reinstalling VMware (Workstation, I trust).  Make sure you have a backup of VMware virtual machines, uninstall VMware, restart the host computer, install VMware, do  a final restart and test.  VMware Workstation needs to be V16.1 to coexist with Hyper-V.

Comment: I am using VMWare Workstation Player, and I did a fresh reinstall of VMWare Workstation Player 16.1.2 build-17966106, but it had the same issue.

Comment: I am not sure if Player co-exists with Hyper-V. Newest version of Workstation works with Hyper-V but it is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem but was unable to find any information on this.
However now I understand why.

In my case I had 2 guest VMs running one ubuntu 22.04 and one windows 10 both of which were in suspended state when I enabled Hyper-V features. The other day when I came to use my VMs I noticed the same side-channel related error and a prompt after that to discard VM state or keep it. The latter did not change the state of VM nor was able to run my VM so I had no choice but discarding.
After that I noticed my windows VM is able to connect but my Ubuntu VM is not which is why I was suspecting the Hyper-V features. Then I tried disabling them but still no network on my Ubuntu. That was when I noticed my network adapter was disabled on Ubuntu OS and I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267043/virtual-machine-ubuntu-20-04-lts-connect-network-is-unreachable?newreg=643b11bca53b42fea78a03766e213489) on Internet.

To sum it up, my problem was not the Hyper-V setting but discarding the VM state (probably!). Changing Hyper-V feature settings was only the trigger to it.